# Python Login Script not looping through accounts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a login script in python without gui (terminal only) that stores the data into a text file and can pull from it, but when I try to login with an account that isn't the most recent one It doesn't recognize it. Here is the code:

```
file = open("passwords.txt", "a")

createOrEnter = input("Would you like to create an account or login?")
if createOrEnter == "create":
    account = input("What is account name?")
    password = input("What is the account password?")
    print(account, password)
    print("Here is account username and password")
    account = str(account)
    password = str(password)
    file.write(account + "," + password + '\n')

if createOrEnter == "login":
    loginSuccess = False
    with open("passwords.txt", 'r') as fileopen:
        lines = fileopen.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            info = line.split(",")
            print(info[0], info[1])
    
        loginaccount = input("Enter account name: ")
        loginpassword = input("Enter account password: ")
        loginpassword = str(loginpassword) + "\n"
        for line in lines:
            if loginaccount == info[0] and loginpassword == info[1]:
                print("You have access to the account")
                loginSuccess = True
        
    if not loginSuccess:
        print("Incorrect password or account not found")
```

Comment: I find it suspicious that you open the same file twice.

Comment: You need to close the file to flush the output buffer.

Comment: Look closely at your second `for line in lines:` loop - there's nothing that would assign `info` there.

Comment: Instead of adding `\n` to `loginpassword`, the normal way to process a file is to strip() it first. You can also use the `csv` module to read and write the file, it will do the stripping and splitting automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login script has a logic issue in the login part. The problem arises because you are not correctly checking each account-password pair from the file against the inputted login credentials.

Also you do not close the file so it may not shuffle data to file.

I commented edited parts on below code:

```
file = open("passwords.txt", "a")

createOrEnter = input("Would you like to create an account or login? ")
if createOrEnter == "create":
    account = input("What is account name? ")
    password = input("What is the account password? ")
    print(f"Here is account username and password: {account}, {password}")
    # Writing account and password to the file
    file.write(account + "," + password + '\n')
    file.close()  # Close the file after writing

if createOrEnter == "login":
    loginSuccess = False
    with open("passwords.txt", 'r') as fileopen:
        lines = fileopen.readlines()
        loginaccount = input("Enter account name: ")
        loginpassword = input("Enter account password: ")
        loginpassword = loginpassword + "\n"

        for line in lines:
            info = line.split(",")
            # Compare each line's account and password with the input
            if loginaccount == info[0] and loginpassword == info[1]:
                print("You have access to the account")
                loginSuccess = True
                break  # Exit the loop if match is found

    if not loginSuccess:
        print("Incorrect password or account not found")
```